# Handling StoreGeneratedPatterns in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have setup a similar databse to the adventureworks,i have a bussiness entity table with 3 rows,and company and people tables,that have my businessentityID as FK and PK.What i want to do exactly is;i want to generate an ID in my bussinessentitiestable,then feed the ID to the other tables.How do i deal with this in entity framework?

Tried the following codes but i still get a store generated pattern error;

```
            //BusinessEntity entity = new BusinessEntity();


                //Person person = new Person();

                //Person person = new Person();
                //person.BusinessEntity = new BusinessEntity();
                //person.FirstName = "ali";
                //person.LastName = "veli";


                //db.People.Add(person);






                BusinessEntity entity = new BusinessEntity();
                entity.Person = new Person();
                entity.Person.FirstName = "asasas";



                db.BusinessEntities.Add(entity);



                db.SaveChanges();
```

[image]

Comment: What is this "store generated pattern error"? Is it an exception? Does it compile? MOAH INFO NEEDED.

Comment: it complies,EF also validates,but when I try to save it i get the following error:{"A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'BusinessEntityID'."}

Comment: What i want to know is how to use this sort of database design in EF.

Comment: Is that an exception? If it is, it would be nice if you include the FULL exception and stack trace. What do you mean by "when I try to save it"? What is `it`? What do you do to try to "save"? Where is your source code? Where is your edmx, programmer can't read diagrams, we read text files.

Comment: Perhaps you should either upload your entire project OR read this http://sscce.org

Comment: `Person.BusinessEntityID` can't be store generated. It should copy its primary key from `BusinessEntity` when it's created.